# Regex that matches path string inside url(" ") but not base64

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Hi I'm trying a lot about this and I'm not reaching the solution.

I'm reading a CSS file and I want to match the path strings **inside** the `url(" ")`.
In the file there are also base64 sources that starts with `url("data:` and i don't want those.

**EDIT:**
But now I'm testing with this https://regex101.com/
I digit `url\(\".\"\)` and it give me nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Biffen That's not mt case, I know regex but I can't get with this case.

Comment: `url\(\".\"\)` (`"` shouldn’t need escaping, BTW) will match a *single* character between the quotes.

Comment: @Biffen ok thanks, sorry for the bad link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?!` for negative lookahead: `url\(\"((?!data:).*)\"\)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/0A8iyF/1 why it gives me just "Group 1. `g`"? He's just grouping the last char?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Try `url\(\"((?!data:).*)\"\)`. Updated my answer.